# Bind event to div but 'not' inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of divs that looks like this

```
<div class="videoThumbnail" data-videoid="4">
   <div class="video"><img src="some/Url" alt="video thumbnail preview"/></div>
   <div class="title">I'm a video</div>
   <div class="download"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s"></span></div>
</div>
```

Then I am binding an event to the `videoThumbnail` class. That function works fine and well but I now need to bind another event for when `download` is clicked. My two bind events look like this.

```
//Bind selecting a thumbnail to change the video
$( '.videoThumbnail' ).not( '.download' ).on( 'click', function ( t ) {
    alert('you are doing thumbnail stuff');
} );
//Bind download on the litle download icon
$( '.download' ).on( 'click', function ( t ) {
    alert('you want to download this');
} );
```

I would like the first bind event on `videoThumbnail` to only happen when it's not selecting the `download` within it. Unfortunately whenever i press the `download` icon both functions execute. How can I bind the first event to the `videoThumbnail` without binding it to the `download` that's inside of it?

Comment: Stop event propagation for click event on .download

Comment: since the first click function only applies to two elements you can also bind directly to them `$( '.videoThumbnail .video, .videoThumbnail .title' ).on( 'click', function ( t ) {
        alert('you are doing thumbnail stuff');
    } );`

Comment: @miguelmpn while that would work for this, I also have them in a for loop and there's 2 sets of them on the page, I thought that information irrelevant to the question though so I left it out.

Comment: You can have different childs? but at least `.download` is always present?

Comment: You're right, it would always be the same classes, so that too is a viable answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Code

```
$('.download').on('click', function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   // the click code..
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping propagtion will prevent the event from bubbling, thereby preventing any parent event listener from being notified of the event that was dispatched. This *may* have inadvertent side-effects resulting in other unintended events being suppressed.

A better approach is to check if `event.target` is the `.download` element or a descendant element of `.download`.

```
$('.videoThumbnail').on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.download').length) {
    // clicked on ".videoThumbnail" and "event.target" is not ".download"
  }
});
```

Here is an example demonstrating that:

```js
$('.videoThumbnail').on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.download').length) {
    alert('clicked on ".videoThumbnail" and "event.target" is not ".download"');
  }
});


$('.download').on('click', function(event) {
  alert('clicked on the ".download" element');
});
```

```css
.videoThumbnail { border: 1px solid; }
.download { background: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videoThumbnail" data-videoid="4">
  <div class="video">
    <img src="some/Url" alt="video thumbnail preview" />
  </div>
  <div class="download"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s">download</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Stopping propagtion will prevent any other events from being fired._ Huh? It will stop this click event from bubbling, but it won't affect any other events.

Comment: @Mathletics Correct. I clarified by stating that it will prevent any parent event listener from being notified of the event that was fired.